# Оптимизация sql select запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Были заданы вопросы на собеседовании:
1) *Как бы вы оптимизировали следующий запрос (показан полный скрипт таблицы содержащей смс-сообщения; приведите обоснование своего выбора)?*

```
create table dbo.sms
( id           int identity primary key clustered
, login        varchar(64)   --логин отправителя
, source       varchar(21)   --подпись
, destination  varchar(21)   --получатель
, data         nvarchar(140) --текст
, send_date    datetime      --время отправки
, client_name  varchar(32)   --название компании клиента
, account_name varchar(128)  --менеджер
)

select *
from dbo.sms
where login = @a and send_date > @b and destination = @c
```

Мой ответ был:

```
declare 
@a varchar(64),@b datetime,@c varchar(21)
select
@a = '7778885458', @b = '2017-12-09', @c = 'Polutchatel'
select *
from dbo.sms (nolock)
where login = @a  and send_date > @b and destination = @c
```

2)
*Требуется максимально быстро строить следующий отчет (по произвольной дате):
client_name, send_date, sms_cnt (количество сообщений)

Какие есть варианты решения данной задачи (пожалуйста, развернуто, плюсы и минусы подходов)?*
*send_date* включает временную составляющую
Мой ответ:

```
select 
      client_name, send_date, count(id) smscount
from dbo.sms (nolock)
group by client_name, send_date
```

Проверьте плз, правильно ли ответы

Comment: В первом вы толком ничего и не изменили. nolock наверное что то ускорит. может речь шла о том какие индексы построить ? На второй вопрос ответ не верен. Там специально указано что в поле даты есть время, значит group by по дате сгруппирует только записи которые были в одну и ту же секунду. А явно не до дня. Ну и опять же мне вопрос не ясен, что значит по произвольной дате, если по конкретной то видимо эта дата должны быть в where. И оптимизация разная бывает, в том числе например создание таблицы с готовыми группированными данными

Comment: @Mike, а если преобразовать на date?                                                 
select client_name, cast(send_date as date), count(id) smscount
from dbo.sms (nolock)
group by client_name, cast(send_date as date)

Comment: Да, это я и имел ввиду, cast до date сделает то что требуется, если требование выдать всю таблицу с разбивкой по датам. Но если диапазон дат большой, то это конечно медленно. А "максимально быстро", это только разные виды заранее кешировать информацию (если конечно "по произвольной дате" не понимать как по одной единственной дате, которую можно ограничить в where (при наличии индекса)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обоих случаях надо добавить соответствующие индексы.

В первом случае возможно композитный по `login`, `send_date`, `destination` - надо уточнить какие еще запросы будут выполняться с этой таблицей. Порядок столбцов в композитном индексе - в начале стоит указывать столбцы с большей кардинальностью.

Пример:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_SMS_Login_SendDate_Destination
    ON dbo.Sms (login, destination, send_date);
```

Во втором - от вас, скорее всего, ожидали услышать об использовании ["Indexed View"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views)

Пример:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;  
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,  
    QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;  
GO  

CREATE VIEW dbo.v_sms
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS
    SELECT client_name, CAST(send_date as DATE) as send_date, count(id) as sms_cnt
    FROM dbo.sms
    GROUP BY client_name, CAST(send_date as DATE);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_v_sms   
    ON dbo.v_sms (client_name, send_date);
GO
```

Comment: а сами запросы правильные?

Comment: добавил такой индекс CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_SMS_Login_SendDate_Destination ON 
dbo.Sms (login, send_date, destination)

Comment: @Zhandos, я думаю от вас ожидали что вы предложите создать подходящие индексы - запрос указанный в вопросе изменять, по-моему, не нужно